# construct a smooth non-vanishing tangent vector field

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds

Fix $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Construct a smooth non-vanishing tangent vector field on $S^{2m-1}$

### My attempt

Let $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ be a manifold. A smooth tangent vector field on $M$ is a smooth function $V:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $V(x) ≡ Vx\in TxM$ fir all $x\in M$.

Smooth non-vanishing means the derivatives won't vanish I am assuming

I don't really know how to do this...

Comment: As a starting point, can you construct one non-vanishing vector field on $\mathbb S^1$ (that is, $m=1$?). Note non-vanishing mean $V(x) \neq 0$, not the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

It is very classical.

Consider $S^{2n-1}$ as the unit sphere in $\bf C^n$ with its standard hermitian norm ; it has equation $ 1= \sum _{i=1}^n \vert z_i\vert ^2$.

If $z=(z_1,...,z_n)\in S$, then $V(z)=iz$ is orthogonoal to $z$, and therefore tangent to $S$.

proof : the curve $t\to \exp it. z$ belongs to $S$ and its derivative at $t=0$ is $iz$.

The field $V(z)=iz$ is therefore a nowhere vanishing field on $S$.

Comment: Thanks! What is a hermitian norm? We haven't learned that

Comment: And how exactly do you jump to the conclusion that if $z=(z_1,...,z_n)\in S$ then $V(x)=iz$ is orthogonal to $z$ ?

Comment: If a curve $c(t)$ belongs to a submanifold $M$, its derivative $c'(0)$ belongs to the tangent space $T_{c(0)}M$